# About maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I´m trying to solve a problem of cancellation of reflexive finitely generated modules over normal noetherian domains.  When $R$ is regular domain with $\dim R \le 2$, for finitely generated modules,  reflexive is equivalent to projective.

Now I´m studying the case $\dim R=2$ and $R$ normal. In this hypothesis, reflexive modules are **maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules**.

I´m looking for **references about this topic**, with especial emphasis in *lifting of homomorphism* between factors of maximal CM modules: something like "... an homomorphism $M/IM\to N/IN$ can be lift to an homomorphism $M\to N...$"; *indescomponibles* maximal CM modules are welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to look at this paper:
http://www.springerlink.com/content/8r44x50448644568/

on deformations of MCM modules and  the references there.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` appears to be broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...

Answer (score 2):

This review seems perfect for your needs: [Maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over surface singularities](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0117) (Burban, Drozd)

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¡Ya le había echado el ojo!